# Не отрабатывает hal_uart_rxcpltcallback

Tags: c++, c, stm32, uart, freertos

Всем здаровеньки. Такая проблема появилась. Использую *FreeRtos* на *stm32f4* возникла такая задача - необходимо по прерыванию обрабатывать пакет данных приходящих по USART. Переопределил **weak** функцию **hal_uart_rxcpltcallback**.

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
        uint8_t str[] = "Hello world UART\r\n\0";
        HAL_UART_Transmit(huart, str, sizeof(str), 30);
}
```

При отправлении сообщения - ничего не происходит (использую *FTDI*). После отправки большого количества данных, прерывание все таки вызывается, но в структуре **UART_HandleTypeDef** значение **RxXferSize = 0**.

После решил переопределить функцию **HAL_UART_ErrorCallback**

```
void HAL_UART_ErrorCallback (UART_HandleTypeDef * huart){
        //breakpoint
        }
```

В итоге оказалось, что после вызова предыдущей функции сразу вызывается и эта функция. В ней значение **RxXferSize = 39** и поднимается флаг переполнения. Если извлечь данные из буфера, то там действительно есть те данные, которые отправлялись, но очевидно часть данных потерялась из-за переполнения.

Проблема в том, что прерывание должно отрабатывать как только приходит пакет (там есть программные флаги). Явно функция работает не правильно, как это можно исправить? В чем может быть проблема?

Во *FreeRtOS* уровень прерывания стоит 5, что является максимальным. К слову, при отправке данных, прерывание на отправку вызывается сразу, вектор прерывания один, следовательно уровни у них едины.

Comment: 1) Покажите весь ваш код, потому как вы выдрали кусок кода и по нему ничего не понятно что и как происходит. А конкретно, нужен код где вы `HAL_UART_Receive` вызываете. 2) Не понятно, при отправке или при приеме проблема. Вы пробовали поэтапно решать проблему? Сначала настроить нормально прием, а потом передачу.

Comment: И да. Вызывать напрямую отправку находясь в калбэке прерывания (к тому же наивысшего приоритета) - это очень плохая практика. Не исключено, что в этом и есть основная проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После проведенных тестов понял вот что, это в целом решило мой вопрос.

1. То, что прерывание вызывалось, когда отпускалась линия ничто иное
   как шум на линии, который воспринимался как один символ, что в итоге
   дало ошибочное суждение.
2. Прерывание **hal_uart_rxcpltcallback** вызывается только при условии
   вызова функций работающих с прерыванием, то есть **HAL_UART_Receive_IT**
   или **HAL_UART_Receive_DMA**. Никаким иным образом оно вызываться не
   должно.
3. Для приема неизвестно длины пакета можно использовать несколько
   методов, но опишу один, самый простой (про сложные через IDLE строк
   можно посмотреть на ютубе). При использовании DMA можно реализовать
   прерывание по одному символу, при использовании IT такого результата
   не будет, так как будут теряться символы.

Если используете *CUBEMXIDE* при генерации кода, то убедитесь, что инициализация *UART* идет после инициализации *DMA* (иначе ничего работать не будет), этот ***баг*** известен, но найти с первого раза информацию о нем мне не удалось, так что оставлю ее здесь. Что касается того, что **hal_uart_rxcpltcallback** вызывалось после переполнения буффера, то мне не удалось найти точного подтверждения причины этому, после нескольких компиляций с разными входами этот *баг* пропал сам, так же как и появился. Так или иначе, триггер этой функции лежит в функциях приема.

Comment: `Прерывание hal_uart_rxcpltcallback вызывается только при условии вызова функций работающих с прерыванием, то есть HAL_UART_Receive_IT или HAL_UART_Receive_DMA. Никаким иным образом оно вызываться не должно.` Вообще-то должно. Это `rxhalfcallback` должно только в режиме DMA.

Comment: `этот баг известен` Это не баг, это фича. Порядок инициализации ставится такой, какой сделали при настройке в кубе. Если столкнулись с этим и не хотите постоянно фиксить порядок инициализации после генерации проекта, то можно подредактировать порядок инициализации в строке `ProjectManager.functionlistsort` в `.ioc` файле.

Comment: *Вообще-то должно.* Это какими еще?